# How do I create a random stack of containers in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, figma

see this : -

[image]

I am trying to replicate this in Flutter but seems impossible

Notice how the "Linguistics" pill perfectly fits between healthcare and data science

and this : -

[image]

I tried simple Row/Columns but they had overflow errors

Stack/Positioned was working until the containers started overlapping each other

Answer (score 1):

You can use positioned with stack and customize for yourself. Output is below.
[image: output]

```
Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  left: 40,
                  top: 42,
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                    angle: math.pi / 20,
                    child: Chip(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                      label: Text("IT & Development"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 80,
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                    angle: -math.pi / 12,
                    child: Chip(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                      label: Text("Healthcare"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 87,
                  top: 112,
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                    angle: math.pi / 6,
                    child: Chip(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                      label: Text("IT & Development"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 30,
                  top: 130,
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                    angle: math.pi / 10,
                    child: Chip(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                      label: Text("IT & Development"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```